# how to create p12 file without password?

Tags: code-signing

I'm attempting to sign an iOS Enterprise application via 3rd party app creation tool, FlipLet.

From my keychain, I export the distribution certificate to obtain a p12 for signing.  When it prompts for password I hit OK to leave it blank then enter admin password to allow the export.  After it's done, I open the p12 file and it prompts for password, which I wouldn't expect because there was none set.  I can just hit enter to bypass as if it recognizes there isn't one.

Any idea how to get it to not prompt as the signing tool is gettin hung on it. I've tried the app iReSign and it fails as well, I assume from the same issue.

Comment: Hi Steve can you give more info regarding which service you are using.

Comment: Sorry, edited the details. I've created the certs via the Apple Enterprise Developer site.  The export of the cert is occurring from within my keychain.

Comment: I've exported .p12 files for Push Notifications and uploaded them into the Accengage website. When I create them I always get prompted to set a password, on the Accengage website I have a field where I set the password, if any, for the .p12 certificate. Which signing tool are you using?

Comment: T.V. Thanks for your response.  It was found to be an error within the service providers software.